# How does Emacs select which thread to run?

Tags: threading

If a thread does a `thread-yield` then how does Emacs select which thread to run next? Does it simply select the oldest one waiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thread-yield` simply unlocks a global lock, calls the pthread `sched_yield` function (or something similar on other platforms), and then relocks the global lock. All such threads will end up waiting for the global lock, trying to reacquire it. Whichever one happens to do so will be the one to run next. See the C function `yield_callback` in thread.c in the Emacs source.